# How to hide a text after 5 sec using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I hide the #results after 5 secs ? I tried this but it does not work.

```
$('#results').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).hide();
```

What I had is this one

```
$('#results').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put a duration on your `hide()` call and it will work like this:

```
$('#results').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).hide(1);
```

The issue is that `hide()` without any parameters is just an immediate operation.  It doesn't go through the fx queue so therefore, it doesn't come after the `.delay(5000)`.  But, if you give a duration to the function like `.hide(1)`, then it becomes an animation and it goes through the fx queue and thus will come after the `.delay(5000)`.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wzbtU/

---

From the [jQuery doc for `hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

*When a duration is provided, .hide() becomes an animation method.*

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like:

```
$('#results').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#results').hide();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: You don't actually need a separate setTimeout call.  You can use the built-in `.delay()` with `.hide()`.  See my answer for how to make it work.

Comment: @jfriend00: True, but I'd argue it the other way: you don't need to turn it into an animation if all you want to do is delay it a fixed period of time.

Comment: I just think it's easier to use jQuery's built-in animation queue and chain `.delay(5000).hide(1);` onto the end of the line versus a separate setTimeout call and I think it's useful to know how to get `show()` and `hide()` to sequence themselves with other jQuery animations if needed.  But, there are always a lot of ways to do this so that's a personal choice.

Comment: @jfriend00: Different things are easier to different people, but I completely agree that it's *useful* to know how to get `show()` and `hide()` to cooperate with other jQuery animations (I didn't know that either!).  I've already upvoted your answer, and I was just responding to your comment on my answer.  No worries.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout("$('#results').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');", 5000);
```

The reason why `.delay(5000)` doesn't work is because `.hide()` isn't included in the animation queue.

Comment: No downvote, but you really shouldn't pass a string to `setTimeout()`.  Always use an anonymous function instead: it's both faster and safer.

Comment: @DanielPryden thanks for that! I didn't know it could accept a function. I've been doing it wrong this whole time...

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery's fadeOut method is nifty:

`$('#results').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');`